# Printing a line of a file given line number

Tags: bash, unix

Is it possible, in UNIX, to print a particular line of a file? For example I would like to print line 10 of file `example.c`. I tried with `cat`, `ls`, `awk` but apparently either these don't have the feature or I'm not able to properly read the `man` :-).

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Using awk:

```
awk 'NR==10' file
```

Using sed:

```
sed '10!d' file
```

Comment: For efficiency, you should quit after printing the line: `awk 'NR==10 {print;exit}'`; Anders Lindahl has the sed answer.

Answer (score 7):

```
sed -n '10{p;q;}' example.c
```

will print the tenth line of `example.c` for you.

Answer (score 5):

Try head and tail, you can specify the amount of lines and where to start.

To get the third line:

```
head -n 3 yourfile.c | tail -n 1
```

Comment: I just want to show the given line, not the whole amount until that line.

Comment: Added a better example of combining head and tail.

Answer (score 2):

`head -n 10 /tmp/asdf | tail -n 1`

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately, all other solutions which use `head`/`tail` will NOT work incorrectly if line number provided is larger than total number of lines in our file.

This will print line number N or **nothing** if N is beyond total number of lines:

```
grep "" file | grep "^20:"
```

If you want to cut line number from output, pipe it through `sed`:

```
grep "" file | grep "^20:" | sed 's/^20://'
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
cat -n <yourfile> | grep ^[[:space:]]*<NUMBER>[[:space:]].*$
```

cat -n numbers the file

the regex of grep searches the line numbered ;-)
The original mismatched as mentioned in the comments.
Te current one looks for the exact match.
- i.e. in the particular cas we need a line starting with an arbitrary amount (*) of spaces the  followed by a space followed by whatever (.*)

In case anyone thumbles over this regex and doesn't get it at all - here is a good tutorial to get you started: http://regex.learncodethehardway.org/book/ (it uses python regex as an example tough).

Comment: if you know how to regex it won't... ^[[:space:]]*<NUMBER>[[:space:]]+.*$
but feel free to spend the -1 if it makes you feel any better...

Comment: I do know how to use regular expressions. Fix your answer and I'll remove my down vote.

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

```
sed '10q;d' file
```